# simple loop error in objC

Tags: objective-c

Hello
I have a loop and I have issues when int11=21 and when i=7.

```
-(NSString *)print01:(int)int11{
    int n =128;
    char array12[7];
    NSString *str;

if(int11==0)
 return str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00000000"];


    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        if ((int11-n)>=0){
             //When i=7 then int11=1 and n=1, the "i" here is 7
                      array12[j]='1'; 
              //and here is become 49!!!

            int11-=n;

        }
        else 
            array12[j]='0';

        n=n/2;
        NSLog(@"Last %d",j);
    }


   str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",array12];

    return str;
}
```

Comment: What `i` do you mean? There is only a `j`.

Comment: haha I am just testing. array12 is an array that holds zeros and ones as chars. j is for the loop. int11 is a parameter for print01 function and is integer. I have problem when int11 is 21 and when i=7.

Comment: @user622203 Testing the limits of your own sanity? :-) Glad to hear it's just a temporary thing, although I can't imagine why you wouldn't just use meaningful variable names all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char array12[7];` and `for(int j=0;j<8;j++)` and `array12[j]='1';` induce an out-of-bounds problem.

Comment: what do you mean? array[0-7] and j=0-7.  Where is the problem?

Comment: @user622203 array[7] has 7 "entries". With the index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. You don't start to count with 0 in this case.